# How to get a list of ports that Java application communicating

Tags: java, sockets, port, lan

I have a Java application that communicates with an API. So my application gets data by calling API and also sending data to the API. I have an idea to get all the port numbers that my application communicates. I looked at some socket programming tutorials but didn't help me to achieve what I need. Is that possible to get all the port numbers that my application communicates If it is possible How can I do that? And I am using `Windows 10`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It'd probably help if you mention which operating system you're using

Comment: Look up `netstat` command. It  will not probably help you with finding the ports for your specific application but you can find what ports are being used by Java, which you can further filter out.

Comment: @shyam Thank you for your answer. But is there any `Java Program` or anything that exactly does what I need?